# Razor, ASP.Net, user authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am wondering why the following:

```
             @if(Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsAnonymous){
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Location", "Index", "Location")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Map", "Map", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Help", "Help", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
             @}else if(Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsAuthenticated){
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Location", "Index", "Location")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Service", "Index", "Service")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Service Assignment", "Index", "ServiceAssignment")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Content Management", "Index", "Content")</li>
                </ul>
             @}
```

Is throwing the following error:

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'Write' takes 0
>   arguments

This error is thrown on my `else if` block. I am new to ASP.net and razor, but from my understanding what I did is correct no? Since they both are Boolean returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need the "@" in the else if.

Try like this:

```
        @if(Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsAnonymous){
           <ul id="menu">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Location", "Index", "Location")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Map", "Map", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Help", "Help", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        }else if(Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsAuthenticated){
           <ul id="menu">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Location", "Index", "Location")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Service", "Index", "Service")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Service Assignment", "Index", "ServiceAssignment")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Content Management", "Index", "Content")</li>
            </ul>
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your razor syntax is goofed.  You should surround the entire if/else if block with the `@{}` and remove the @ symbol from the various closing braces in your if/else branch.

```
@{
    if (Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsAnonymous)
    {
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Location", "Index", "Location")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Map", "Map", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Help", "Help", "Home")</li>
        </ul>
    }
    else if (Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Location", "Index", "Location")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Service", "Index", "Service")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Service Assignment", "Index", "ServiceAssignment")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Content Management", "Index", "Content")</li>
        </ul>
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just use @if.  Since the HTML tags within each block are valid, Razor can figure out that the else if and closing bracket are code.

Comment: @JasonBerkan - good point.  I think that these two methods are just style choices at that point.